# Unable to understand how list is dynamically updated during runtime?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```py
def demo(v,l=[]):
     l.append(v)
     return l
l1=demo(10) #output [10]
l2=demo(21,[])
l3=demo('a')
print('List 1: ', l1) #output=[10]
print('List 2: ', l2) #output=[21]
print('List 3: ', l3) #output=[10,'a']
```

How is the list updating even if I am using different objects for the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default arguments of functions (here `l=[]`) are not re-created upon function calls, but only created once when the function is defined. Thus, it really is the same object `l` that is referred to for all calls to `demo()`.

This is usually not the behavior one wants. The typical way to get around it is to use an *immutable* object as the default value, often `None`:

```py
def demo(v, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = []  # Create new empty list
    l.append(v)
    return l
```